# Use TikZ "circle connection bar" with non circular shapes

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, mindmaps

Is there any way to use the `circle connection bar` feature from the `mindmap` Tikz library with non circular node shapes?

Here a non working Example:

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}


\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[circle, draw] (a) {a};
        \node[rectangle, rounded corners, draw, above right=of a] (b) {b};

        \path (a) to[circle connection bar] (b);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: No, not really. Take a look at the PGFmanual and the sections about the `circle connection bar` decoration and the `circle connection bar` to-path. If you use the decoration, you can give the values `start radius` and `end radius`. It would also be best to use a true rectangular shape with rounded corners so that the anchors are set correctly. However, this will all get very complex if you want to connect to irregular things/shape.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Do you want to write an answer? ('No' can be an answer as well, however boring it is.)

Answer (score 2):

Expanding [@Qrrbrbirlbel's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141308/use-tikz-circle-connection-bar-with-non-circular-shapes#comment319327_141308) into an answer:

No, not really. Take a look at the PGF manual and the sections about the `circle connection bar` decoration and the `circle connection bar` to-path. If you use the decoration, you can give the values `start radius` and `end radius`. It would also be best to use a true rectangular shape with rounded corners so that the anchors are set correctly. However, this will all get very complex if you want to connect to irregular things/shape.